# How to make Python turtle window respond while waiting for further data

Tags: python, loops, turtle-graphics

My code takes laptop's battery data and makes a graph with the data in Python turtle.
The code takes a datapoint every 2 minutes and prints it on the turtle screen. The problem is, while waiting for another datapoint, the turtle window doesn't respond and I can't make it active.

The turtle window works perfectly when I add turtle.done() in the end but the code doesn't continue after I close the turtle window, which I don't want, I want the window to be visible all the time.

Is there any good way to make the window "act" like with turtle.done() but it continues the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your needs correctly, then you might be able to use the turtle screen's `ontimer()` method.  You want to do `done()` which turns control over to tkinter's event loop.  But by having an `ontimer()` event, which reinvokes itself as the last thing it does, you can have event-friendly code constantly checking for more datapoints.  Roughly:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def my_update():
    #  get the new data
    # ...

    # draw the new data
    turtle.forward(...)  

    # reinvoke one-shot (5 secs. from now)
    screen.ontimer(my_update, 5000)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()

# invoke one-shot (5 secs. from now)
screen.ontimer(my_update, 5000)

screen.mainloop()
```